# Re order the clues

Tags: knowledge, history

The clues are out of order when decoded. What's the correct order?

1. A common color
2. A rank in the army
3. A popular candy bar
4. A publishing house
5. A roofer for cottage
6. Orwells' true surname
7. An indisputable rule of science
8. A month of the year
9. Paradise on earth
10. An official serving a nobleman

Comment: Are the tags correct? E.g. Is there a riddle?

Comment: Should that be 'Paradise' not 'Paradis'?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark\bf{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. Brown
>  2. Major
>  3. Heath
>  4. Macmillan
>  5. Thatcher
>  6. Blair
>  7. Law
>  8. May
>  9. Eden
>  10. Bannerman (actually Tom's suggestion of Chamberlain fits better)

They are all

> British Prime Ministers

In order

> 10,7,9,4,3,5,2,6,1,8.

Comment: Looks good!  No. 10 may also be Chamberlain.

Comment: Rule of science could also be 'Spencer Compton' as in the 'Compton Effect' or 'William Cavendish'  - as in the gravitational constant.

Comment: @Tom oh yes, that fits much better (and is the whole surname), well spotted!